# What bad things happen if Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException is invoked directly?

Tags: java, exception

What are the negative consequences of chucking a checked exception directly to the UncaughtExceptionHandler?

```
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    verb();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this,e);
                }
            }
        };
```

Clearly, there are (supposed to be) consequences to the application -- whoever wrote verb() thought this particular condition was supposed to be handled.  Assuming I'm willing to ignore that, what else will go wrong?

Are there consequences to calling the ExceptionHandler *before* the thread is about to terminate?

Comment: I believe that the code is strictly equivalent to `public void run() { verb(); }` (since by definition the uncaughtExceptionHandler is supposed to catch unhandled exceptions).

Comment: Unless `verb()` throws a checked exception in which case you have to catch it and the code just lets the default handler deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be negative sequences.
If you have not explicitely set your custom handler then the `ThreadGroup` method will be 
called [which](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29):

> This method determines if the Throwable argument is an instance of
>   ThreadDeath. If so, nothing special is done.    Otherwise, a message
>   containing the thread's name, as returned from the thread's getName
>   method, and a stack backtrace, using the Throwable's printStackTrace
>   method, is printed to the standard error stream.

If you have set your custom the most probable is it will just log something. So you will just see a log of the thread and the stack trace.
Unless your custom handler does something specific that should be done only when the thread terminates but from the OP it seems that this is not the case.

Comment: If a custom handler has been set, the code seems superfluous.

Comment: @assylias:I think the code is nonsensical but does not have any "dangerous" side-effects that the OP is worried about